# A question about PDE argument involving monotone convergence theorem and Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading [this paper](http://www.gillesfrancfort.com/Site/Publications_files/published.version.BF91%20copy.pdf). In it there is the following argument (see page 240).

[image]

Firstly, what precisely does the author mean by the displayed equation after 66? The PDE in (65) only holds weakly.. $b(\overline{v}_n)$ is only in $H^1(0,T;H^{-1})\cap L^\infty(0,T;L^s)$ and $\overline{v}_n \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$. He just integrates it in time.. I don't follow.

Secondly, I am lost with the spaces when he says that $\int_0^T \overline{v}_n(s)\;ds$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space $L^\infty(0,T;W^{1,r}_0)$. And then he uses the monotone convergence theorem to say that $\overline{v}_n$ convreges strongly in $L^1(\Omega \times (0,T))$ to some $\overline{v}$. Any explanation appreciated.

I posed this [here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851479/sobolev-spaces-and-using-monotone-convergence-theorem-dont-understand-a-paper) but did not receive an answer.

Comment: Yes, also taking into account initial data.

Comment: There's no issue with applying the comparison principle. I think you misread my OP. My problem is with the displayed equation *after* (66). The PDE does not hold pointwise a.e. because it isn't smooth enough (the exact spaces it lies in are written in the paper just above where I cut the image but I reproduced it in my post) so I don't understand what the author did.

Comment: What's wrong with writing it in a distributional sense? $b(u)$ is in the right space $L^\infty(0,T,L^1(\Omega)$ it is written before.

Comment: How does something like $\int_0^t f_n(s)$ make sense though? I have never seen any distributional equation with terms like that.

Answer (score 1):

Hy

First: take $\varphi_n(t) w(x)$ where $\varphi(t)\in C_0([0,T))$ and $w\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. If $\varphi_n$ is well chosen and converges to the characteristic function of the set $[0,t]$ you will understand the formulation.

Second: to be short, you have to mix the fact that $\int_0^t f_n(s,x)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(\Omega)$, that ($n$ fixed) $\int_0^t f_n(s,x)$ is continuous in $L^1(0,T; L^1(\Omega))$ and the De Giorgi regularity result.
Since $\bar{v}_n$ is monotonically inscreasing in $n$ you have almost convergence to some $\bar{v}$ and then proving that $\bar{v}_n$ converges strongly to $v$ in $L^1(0,T;L^1(\Omega))$ is equivalent to prove that 
$\int_0^T\int_\Omega \bar{v}_n dxdt$ goes to $\int_0^T\int_\Omega \bar{v} dxdt$.
From the previous result (the Cauchy sequence in $L^\infty(0,T;W^{1,q}_0(\Omega))$) you obtain the result.

Comment: Thank you for answering, let me think about it for a bit.

Comment: Do you have any references for arguments like this (eg in some paper)?

Comment: No, I have no reference in mind. I think it is classical and with the explanation of the paper you can complete all the arguments.